# Scan this USB for errors constant popup

Tags: windows-7, usb, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption

Whenever I plug in my USB stick on a Windows PC, I get the message that my disk is corrupt and if I would like to fix it.

Note that choosing to fix it brings up this window (I'm using a Dutch system):
[image]

Rough translation:

> Checking removable Disk J:
>
> Options for disk check:
>
> (checkbox) Automatically correct mistakes in the filesystem.
>
> (checkbox) Search corrupted sectors and fix them.
>
> Start Cancel

The search for corrupted sectors box is usually deactivated, but as far as I know it makes little difference in terms of what happens, as I have tried both on and off.

Choosing not to fix it doesn't change anything about the USB's behavior (I can just use it as I would otherwise), and choosing to fix it just brings up the message again when I unplug it safely from the Windows PC.

Additional notes:

- I use this USB stick on Ubuntu as well. Maybe that is related to the issues?
- The stick is formatted as a FAT32 filesystem and is 8GB.

Comment: Do you eject it correctly when using it in Ubuntu? Do you get the issue if you run the check, unplug it and re-plug it, without using it on Ubuntu?

Comment: I always properly unmount it when I eject it on Ubuntu. I don't get the issue if I run the check, unplug it and then replug it without using it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all the data on the USB device.
2. Format back to default settings (FAT32).
3. Remove and reinsert into PC
4. 'Scan this USB' popup reappeared?

   - YES: Very likely hardware failure/failing. Replace USB device.
   - NO: Copy the files back onto the USB device. Then remove and reinsert into PC.
5. 'Scan this USB' popup reappeared after files have been copied back?

   - YES: Very likely hardware failure/failing. Replace USB device.
   - NO: All fixed :)